# Does Sitecore 10.0.1 support SAML with Okta?

Tags: azure, federated-authentication

I am using Sitecore 10.0.1 on the Azure App Services platform.  I would like to implement federated authentication using saml.  I was only able to find documentation using open id connect.  Does Sitecore 10.0.1 support saml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can have a SAML Federated Authentication implementation with Sitecore 10.0.1. Federated Auth is a bring-your-own-auth framework, and while most examples show OpenID Connect, you can implement whatever OWIN-based authentication that you want.

For a SAML implementation, I would recommend trying [Sustainsys.Saml2](https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/stable/). There's a good [blog post from George Chang](https://blogs.perficient.com/2018/06/06/federated-authentication-in-sitecore-9-part-3-implementation-of-saml2p/) which uses exactly that library to implement SAML with Sitecore Federated Authentication.

There's a couple things to take note when doing your own implementation. In order for claims to be transformed, you need to explicitly call it as George does in the `AcsCommandResultCreated` callback. You can configure SAML using the XML metadata you get from your identity provider by setting the `MetadataLocation` property as seen in his example. Also, if you need certs for SAML on your application, you can set the cert info in `SPOptions.ServiceCertificates` with `X509Certificate2`.

Finally, I don't see it in George's blog post, but I believe you need the following transform in your identity provider config:

```xml
<transformation name="Idp Claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.SetIdpClaimTransform, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" />
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to George Chang's article cited above, which describes how to enable SAML2 login from the classic CM login screen, I've written an article on integrating Sustainsys.SAML2 to Sitecore Identity server. Part one is [here](https://www.velir.com/ideas/2021/09/22/connecting-sitecore-identity-to-saml-part-1), and part two will be published shortly.